# Is there any specific word for showing dislike facial expression?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, american-english

Sometimes women twist their faces to express their dislikeness. Is there any specific word for showing such facial expression?

Comment: Hi Medex, men have also been known to twist their faces to show disapproval. Admittedly, it is a very rare phenonemon. Words to describe such actions include 'frown', 'glare' and 'grimace'. If you need more help, please add more information to support your question. Many thanks.

Comment: Why on earth is this limited to women? Men express displeasure and dislike in their facial expressions just as much as women do.

Comment: I didnt know that .. , Well, thank you all for sharing the words .. !!

Comment: http://www.nicoleangeleen.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Sneering-Dick.png

Comment: Good pic, @Tim Romano, but that's Dick's *smile*!

Answer (score 2):

As stated, this question is kind of unanswerable simply because, and as already noted in the comments, there are so many possible emotions being expressed when  *people* "twist" their faces. The research into *kinesics* by Ekman and Friesen is the single best source for the many possible emotions expressed when people "twist" their faces. Underlying all of this are the nearly 2 dozen subcutaneous facial muscles that are fundamental to registering differing intensities of emotion. For instance, Ekman has developed such tremendous facial muscle control that he can contort his face into the expression of any emotion literally at will.

Ekman and Friesen's work dates back several decades which has given them ample time and opportunity to document the cross-cultural significance of a wide variety of facial expressions. In addition, they have catalogued the base emotions and accompanying facial expressions here:

http://www.paulekman.com/universal-facial-expressions/

Answer (score 1):

[Sneer](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sneer) : to smile or laugh at someone or something with an expression on your face that shows dislike and a lack of respect

[Scowl](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scowl) : to look at someone or something in a way that shows anger or disapproval

[Glare](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/glare) :  to express (as hostility) by staring angrily

[Grimace](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grimace) : a facial expression in which your mouth and face are twisted in a way that shows disgust, disapproval, or pain

You mentioned women specifically, but the expression is by no means exclusive to women, and I don't know of any word for it that has a feminine connotation.

Other words for twisting your face are [contort](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contort) or [pinch](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pinch). To make it seem more disapproving, you could add an accusatory "at" at the end. For example, "I hate when you pinch your face at me."

Comment: can you please frame a sentence .. such as i get hurt when you ________ your face ..!!

Comment: @Medex The usual collocation is 'pull one's face'.

Comment: Briefly done, it's a _wince_.

Answer (score 1):

A [wry face (smile)](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/wry+face) :

> - a disdainful grimace

- Her smile was wry as she gazed up at his face.

[image]

Comment: can you please frame a sentence .. such as i get hurt when you ______your face ..!!

Comment: It hurts when I see that wry smile on you face.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a verb to use with *face* as the direct object, I suggest ***screw.***

> She screwed her face in disgust.

Dictionary.com [offers this definition](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/screwed) of *screw* in this context:

> to contort as by twisting; distort (often followed by up)