# What is the word for this facial expression? I stick my tongue out partly, wrinkle my nose, curl my lip and make a sort of mocking “ehh-ehh” sound

Tags: single-word-requests

Sometimes when I am talking to my friends or something and I’m feeling sarcastic, sassy, or mocking I’ll stick my tongue out partly, wrinkle my nose, curl my lip and make a sort of mocking “ehh-ehh” sound. Is there a word for this?

Comment: Is this a gesture only you use? Or do you know other people who do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any specific word for showing dislike facial expression?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/252259/is-there-any-specific-word-for-showing-dislike-facial-expression) 'Grimace' is probably as close as you'll get: 'an ugly, twisted expression on a person's face, typically expressing disgust, pain, or wry amusement.' [Oxford Languages, courtesy of Google].

Comment: You curl only one lip while doing those other things also? Hmm

Comment: Is this like the nyah-nyah-nyah-nyah-nyah-nyah thing that kids do (at least in the UK)? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyah_nyah_nyah_nyah_nyah_nyah), [WordReference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/na-nana-naa-nah-childrens-taunting-song-ne-ner-nyah-neener.2482169/) - I can't find a video though.

Comment: A duplicate of a closed question! But not really a duplicate. Still, not a great question.

Answer (score 0):

Not a word but maybe a phrase like 'pulling a face' or a 'mocking expression.'

Answer (score -1):

It’s called making a face.  You can look it up.